# Docker Socket over SSH

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-registry

can i run docker socket over ssh?
i'm trying to run unix:///var/run/docker.sock but i'm getting the error "Is daemon service running?, Cannnot connect to daemon service"
Jenkins master and the ubuntu machine a very isolated they might as well just be on different machines not even in the same room. Unix domain sockets, the ones that are identified by unix://* are made for communicating within a single local OS kernel, trying to bridge them into remote machine will lead to disaster.
how can i use Docker sock over ssh?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connecting to a Remote Docker Daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56130644/connecting-to-a-remote-docker-daemon)

Answer (score 1):

stephen proposed a solution but i find this one more adequate to your use case.

you can simply use

```
ssh xxx "docker run yyy"
```

or you can use env variables :

- be sure that you have ssh key authentification active
- and call all your docker commands with this env variable defined :
  DOCKER_HOST=remoteservername
  docker will use ssh connection to run commands

you can also use -H (works the same)

see more here
https://betterprogramming.pub/docker-tips-access-the-docker-daemon-via-ssh-97cd6b44a53